# C++ Templates alternative

Tags: c++, templates, generics

Is there any programming paradigm alternative to templates in C++ so the developer can write clean code without compiler warnings and errors like
warning C4251: dll-interface to be used by clients of class 
I want to reach generic programming without the use of templates like using macros and any other facility in C++ except templates

Comment: I'm really shocked from this question.

Comment: So you want templates without templates?

Comment: I would pay solid gold for a programming paradigm that allows the programmer to write code without warnings and errors.

Comment: Templates in C++ are superior to generics. You are just using them in the wrong way, or using them for something they weren't intended for.

Comment: Templates are not really that though to grasp. Most of the time they are way better, and easier to use than macros

Comment: @AraK:  Templates in C++ *are* generics.

Comment: I vaguely remember Boost doing wild things with macros that I can only describe as "preprocessor metaprogramming". You may want to check out what those guys are up to if you're interested in this sort of thing. Sorry I don't recall the exact area I saw it.

Comment: A compiled library contains compiled code. Perhaps it helps to think of both macros and templates as *code generation tools*. They are not "code" by themselves, and so they cannot be packaged into a compiled library.

Comment: I understood from the question that the OP is thinking along the lines of C#/Java. I know they are the main facility in C++ for generic programming, but they are not only for generic programming.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if we had a better idea of your actual intended use case, but in general the best way to provide a DLL-interface-compatible generic interface is to use polymorphism, rather than templates.